# Basic abstract data type program

Tags: java

This is homework but my teacher breezed through this part of the course during the lectures and I'm slightly lost.

We have to create a generic class `Pair <A,B>` like this:

```
public Pair(A itemA, B itemB)

public A first()

public B second()
```

The class will be used to stored and item and it's weight, like for example: `Pencil,15`

I just need a slight push to be able to do this

Comment: Take a look at http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/MutablePair.html

Answer (score 0):

All you really need to do is take the items in the constructor and store them in instance variables, which the `first()` and `second()` methods can return. When you declare the instance variables, you can declare their types as just `A` or `B`.

Comment: Already done it! Just needed something with examples, thank you!